# Why is React-router link not working on onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

```
 <Link to="/final-preview">
            <button  onClick={handleSubmit}>
              Final Preview
            </button>
 </Link>
```

So before the onClick function the Link was working perfectly but after it's not. I'd be really grateful if someone knows some specificity about router link :)

Comment: Can you show the handlesubmit method?

Comment: Any details about the error would help us understand your problem better.

Comment: Also you are navigating to a new route, plus intercepting the click event... This seems to be counter-intuitive. What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: So this is the handleSubmit method :                                                                                            function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPurchaseFormError(validate(purchaseData));
    setIsSubmit(true);
  }      , where setPurchaseFormError is for validating form data /I've watched from here  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYpdEYK25Dc
 /

Comment: And on another component I have:                                                                                            {Object.keys(purchaseFormError).length === 0 && isSubmit ? (
          <FinalPreview purchaseData={purchaseData} />
        ) : (
          <PurchaseForm
            purchaseData={purchaseData}
             />
        )}     , this is when all the information is correct to show FinalPreview, else to stay still on the form.  Idk why i think here can be the error but i need it so i can pass props to the other components.

Comment: you can either customize  your a link tag like  a button or you can add an event to the button to navigate

Comment: Please provide more details for a better understanding

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and more detail about the issue. The reason "it's not working" is extremely insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially try `useNavigate` as a solution instead as

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function ThisPage() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const leavePage = () => {
    navigate("/final-preview");
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick = {leavePage}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ThisPage;
```

In the leave page method, you can handle submitting the preview, before navigating to the next link.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Here is example

First Import React Router

```
import {
  Link as RouterLink,
  Route,
  Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";
```

Add code

```
<Link component={RouterLink} to="/final-preview">
      <button  onClick={handleSubmit}>
       Final Preview
       </button>
 </Link>
```

Comment: Not much actionable info offered in the question. But it's pretty safe to assume from "before the onClick function the Link was working" that the problem is not a failure to import the router libraries.

Comment: Thanks for trying to contribute. Please take time to ensure you understand the question before answering it. If the question is too vague, use comments to ask for more information.